# The correct way to retrieve data from a HttpWebRespose Stream then add text

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, stringbuilder

I am trying to retrieve a web page, add some text at the top of the page then I will be sending off the string. Here is a example framework of what I am trying to do. Is this the correct method or am I doing a big no-no somewhere?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
var responce = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = responce.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(responseString);

var index = sb.ToString().IndexOf("<body>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)+"<body>".Length;
sb.Insert(index, "A lot of text will go here.");
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I guess that will work if it's welformed or at least if theres only one <body> and no literal sections including a <body> and similar nastiness

Comment: <body bgcolor="#ffffff"> etc will fail.

Comment: @Rune FS, I only care about the first <body> in the returned page.

Comment: @Jesper Palm The actuall webiste this will be used on uses <body> for it's tag but thank you for the warning.

Comment: @Scott so if the first <body> happens to be inside the head tag that's still the one you need? In that case i would surely do it by a simple search in a text string

Comment: @Rune FS well <body> will not be in the header text for the page I will be pointing at. What this will be used for is to point at a company intranet page. It will grab the data on the page, add a little information at the top of the page, then send the edited page in a HTML formatted email to specific employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you need to use HttpWebRequest/Response? You could alternatively use the WebClient class like this to achieve the same result:

```
WebClient web_client = new WebClient();
byte[] result = web_client.DownloadData("http://blah...");
string html = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
html.IndexOf("<body>") ...
```

Little bit less code like that as well.

Comment: Or even web_client.DownloadString()

Comment: WebClient was the exact thing I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing, glad I was able to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

At some point, you may want to call responce.Close() and reader.Close()